# Scheduled tasks in Django without Celery?

Tags: python, django, celery

In my application, users have credits (points) linked to their monthly subscription.

I’d like to automatically refill credits for every user at a specific date every month.
Note that for each user, this date is different (depending on the date of the subscription)

I heard about Celery for scheduled tasks, and it seems to fill my needs, but is maybe a little bit overkill. Is there something simpler (and maybe embedded in Django) to do that?

Comment: You can use cron (linux) or windows task scheduler (or whatever it's called) to schedule a custom script, but asking about a recommended tool is off-topic for SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create a service which can check your records and do what actions you need.

This is simple example of a file which is in root directory of project like so:

- manage.py
- **my_service.py**
- project_name

So source code of `my_service.py` could be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
import time
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "project_name.settings")

form django.contrib.auth.models import User
while True:
    rows = User.objects.filter(created___startswith=...)
    if not rows:
        print 'sleep...'
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
    [you actions should be here]
```

and then run it in background by `python my_service.py` command.

Or you can add this script into cron job (If so, then this part will be change):

**Note**: if you want to add it in cron job. you should change `while True` to limited loop like so:

```
form django.contrib.auth.models import User
rows = User.objects.filter(created___startswith=...)
if not rows:
    sys.exit(1)
while R in rows:
    [you actions should be here]
```

Now for adding it in your cron job to be run per 1 hour, have a look into **[this link](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2009/06/15-practical-crontab-examples/)** it has many examples about it.

**Note**: This is just an example. you should change that models name to your models name + queries.

Comment: Thanks for this idea. Not very very elegant since it's gonna make a query every XX seconds on my DB for nothing, but it has the merit to be simple :) A good start.

Comment: @DavidW. I was in several projects that system should process any users inputs which are in `entry` table per second. I've tried via these ways. ;)